# How we can find the message id which we have to provide to gamil api to get the message via python (imap,email module)

Tags: python-3.x, email, gmail, imap, gmail-api

I am able to get the uid and message-id but unable to get decode that message id to use through google api where i can find further information about it.

I want to get the thread id from that message id

Using python3.7

```
import imaplib, email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
username = 'id'
password = 'password'
mail.login(username, password)
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
email_uid = data[0].split()
for uid in email_uid[:
  print(mail.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)'))
```

**please help as soon as possible**

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions ?  It includes additional `FETCH` items for getting the gmail specific id and thread-ids.

Comment: Depending on your usage maybe is worth looking into the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides). If not yo should read the documentation in [IMAP from the google side](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need a uid.

Read it https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-8

This lib may help you: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools